# What do these assignments mean?

Tags: python

A very beginning question:
A small function which controls the zoom of an Excel worksheet's layout.

```
from win32com import client
import os
import shutil
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger,PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
import os,shutil,time

def zoomExcel(file_name):
    excel = load_workbook(filename=base_folder+file_name, data_only=False)
    ws = excel.active
    ws.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
    ws.page_setup.fitToHeight = 1.1
    ws.page_setup.fitToWidth = False
    ws.page_setup.scale = 1.3 #ZOOM 
    excel.save(base_folder+"Enlarged/"+file_name)
```

In the last line, why I cannot save directly "ws", as `ws.save(base_folder+"Enlarged/"+file_name)`
what's the main difference between variables "ws" and "excel" here ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: probably because worksheet is a part of the file and You can't really save just a fraction of file while not saving the rest, that would mean that only this worksheet saved but in a way that it was the only worksheet in the file, since it would overwrite, therefore it probably doesn't have that option

Comment: The author seems to have used `ws` as a simple short cut to `excel.active`, so `excel` is still the workbook loaded.

Comment: See the API docs. [Workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook) supports save; [Worksheet](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet) does not. Also, there's a good [Guide to Excel Spreadsheets in Python With openpyxl](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/).

Comment: @jarmod Thanks very much sir. I've another very beginning question: 
from openpyxl import Workbook, "Workbook" here, is it the same as "Workbook" in openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook(write_only=False, iso_dates=False) ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The class Workbook appears to be declared in openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py but can be imported via: `from openpyxl import Workbook`. Note that the same is not true of Worksheet. The API 'reference' docs for this package leave a lot to be desired (a running theme with Python, unfortunately).